# Upgrading Ubuntu Version

Tags: release-loki, updates, ubuntu

I need to upgrade my elementary to either Ubuntu 16.10 or above, but Loki is still on 16.04. Is there a safe way for me to upgrade my Ubuntu version but keep the elementary look? If not, when will the next release come out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not so simple. elementary OS is more than a look on top of Ubuntu:
https://elementary.io/open-source
elementary OS is always build on a LTS (Long term support) version of Ubuntu, the next LTS (18.04) should be released in April. Meaning that the next elementary OS will be released some time after that, "When it's ready".
More info:
https://medium.com/elementaryos/lets-talk-about-elementary-os-5-0-juno-a3a65b97ee7e